# Encrypt Mac folder to CDROM for use with Windows

Tags: macos, encryption, osx-lion

I have been trying to work out how this is possible to very little avail.

I'm on Mac OS X Lion and need to encrypt CD-R for Windows user.

All I want to do is encrypt a folder containing important website files to CD-R so that I can safely send the files via the post on a CD.

Answer (score 2):

[truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) is a freely-available, cross-platform solution that should work for you.  It can be configured to encrypt directories or special *block files*, that are only accessible with a password.

Presumably you could put the Windows installation files on the CD-ROM as well, in order to make it easier for the recipient to access the data.

Another approach would be using [GPG](http://www.gnupg.org/), to encrypt a `.zip` or `.tar.gz` file, or even zip itself using AES encryption.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will give these a go shortly.